# ifelse statement vectorization in a for loop

Tags: r

I am having trouble with vectorization of a portion of some code involving ifelse statements with multiple conditions in a for loop, and if its possible I have not been able to find anyone with quite the same problem. Below is a sample of my data:

```
> build[1:25, ]
   truckid       readdate_from route_from         to_readdate to_route distance_travelled TTTfrom toTTT timebtwpnts
1   100284 2015-03-13 00:05:00            2015-03-13 00:05:20                 0.349115293    6206  6206          20
2   100284 2015-03-13 00:05:20            2015-03-13 00:15:00                 9.345457793    6206  2420         580
3   100284 2015-03-13 00:15:00            2015-03-13 00:20:00      I15        4.609846782    2420  2420         300
4   100284 2015-03-13 00:20:00        I15 2015-03-13 00:34:34      I15        6.097244827    2420  2420         874
5   100284 2015-03-13 00:34:34        I15 2015-03-13 00:36:52      I15        0.112831213    2420  2420         138
6   100284 2015-03-13 00:36:52        I15 2015-03-13 00:37:52      I15        0.051011669    2420  2420          60
7   100284 2015-03-13 00:37:52        I15 2015-03-13 00:50:00      I15        8.244393968    2420  2420         728
8   100284 2015-03-13 00:50:00        I15 2015-03-13 00:57:06                 7.900808243    2420  6188         426
9   100284 2015-03-13 00:57:06            2015-03-13 00:58:14                 1.298096162    6188  6019          68
10  100284 2015-03-13 00:58:14            2015-03-13 01:03:30                 1.782517401    6019  6188         316
11  100284 2015-03-13 01:03:30            2015-03-13 01:05:18                 0.002000153    6188  6188         108
12  100284 2015-03-13 01:05:18            2015-03-13 01:25:34                 0.052831508    6188  6188        1216
13  100284 2015-03-13 01:25:34            2015-03-13 01:35:00                 6.471993106    6188  6183         566
14  100284 2015-03-13 01:35:00            2015-03-13 01:35:20                 0.398436396    6183  6183          20
15  100665 2015-03-01 20:46:00            2015-03-01 20:51:00                 4.916207734    6180  6188         300
16  100665 2015-03-01 20:51:00            2015-03-01 20:56:00                 4.977879172    6188  6019         300
17  100665 2015-03-01 20:56:00            2015-03-01 20:57:22      I15        1.339368219    6019  2420          82
18  100665 2015-03-01 20:57:22        I15 2015-03-01 21:01:00      I15        3.489645997    2420  2420         218
19  100665 2015-03-01 21:01:00        I15 2015-03-01 21:06:00      I15        5.181996399    2420  2420         300
20  100665 2015-03-01 21:06:16        I15 2015-03-01 21:11:00      I15        4.193124975    2420  2420         284
21  100665 2015-03-01 21:11:00        I15 2015-03-01 21:16:00      I15        3.247763697    2420  2420         300
22  100665 2015-03-01 21:16:00        I15 2015-03-01 21:21:00      I15        4.074412199    2420  2420         300
23  100665 2015-03-01 21:21:00        I15 2015-03-01 21:26:00      I15        4.282198968    2420  2420         300
24  100665 2015-03-01 21:26:00        I15 2015-03-01 21:28:48                 2.661758135    2420  6205         168
25  100665 2015-03-01 21:28:48            2015-03-01 21:31:00                 2.281483570    6205  6030         132
         mins speedbtwpnts stopmove
1   0.3333333  62.84075269        1
2   9.6666667  58.00628975        1
3   5.0000000  55.31816138        1
4  14.5666667  25.11450958        1
5   2.3000000   2.94342294        0
6   1.0000000   3.06070012        0
7  12.1333333  40.76898116        1
8   7.1000000  66.76739360        1
9   1.1333333  68.72273800        1
10  5.2666667  20.30716027        1
11  1.8000000   0.06667178        0
12 20.2666667   0.15640907        0
13  9.4333333  41.16462046        1
14  0.3333333  71.71855135        1
15  5.0000000  58.99449281        1
16  5.0000000  59.73455007        1
17  1.3666667  58.80153156        1
18  3.6333333  57.62718160        1
19  5.0000000  62.18395678        1
20  4.7333333  53.15228842        1
21  5.0000000  38.97316437        1
22  5.0000000  48.89294639        1
23  5.0000000  51.38638762        1
24  2.8000000  57.03767432        1
25  2.2000000  62.22227919        1
```

I successfully coded the following from:

```
res <- numeric(nrow(build))
system.time(for (i in 1:length(build$truckid)){
  res[i] <- i
  ifelse(i == 1,
     res[i] <- build$readdate_from[i],
     ifelse(build$truckid[i] != build$truckid[i-1],
            res[i] <- build$readdate_from[i],
            res[i] <- res[i-1]))
})
build$starttime <- res

build <- within(build,
                pretrip <- paste(truckid,
                                 starttime,
                                 sep = "_"))
```

to:

```
res <- as.numeric(build$readdate_from)
cond <- c(FALSE, (build[-nrow(build), 1] == build[-1, 1]))
system.time(for (i in 1:nrow(build)){
  ifelse(cond[i],
     res[i] <- res[i-1],
     res[i] <- res[i])
})
build$starttime <- res       

build <- within(build,
                pretrip <- paste(truckid,
                                 starttime,
                                 sep = "_"))
```

which runs about 10 times as fast. What I'm now trying to do is do the same with the following block which contain multiple ifelse conditions inside of one for loop:

```
res <- numeric(nrow(build))
system.time(for (i in 1:length(build$pretrip)){
  res[i] <- i
  ifelse(i == 1,
     res[i] <- build$mins[i],
     ifelse(build$pretrip[i] == build$pretrip[i-1] && build$stopmove[i-1] == 1 && build$stopmove[i] == 0,
            res[i] <- build$mins[i],
            ifelse(build$pretrip[i] == build$pretrip[i-1] && build$stopmove[i] == 0 && build$stopmove[i-1] == 0,
                   res[i] <- round(res[i-1] + build$mins[i], 5),
                   ifelse(build$pretrip[i] != build$pretrip[i-1] && build$stopmove[i] == 0,
                          res[i] <- build$mins[i],
                          res[i] <- 0))))
})
build$timestopped <- res
```

This code does what I want, which is aggregate time once a stop is indicated by a zero:

```
> build[1:25, ]
   truckid       readdate_from route_from         to_readdate to_route distance_travelled TTTfrom toTTT timebtwpnts
1   100284 2015-03-13 00:05:00            2015-03-13 00:05:20                 0.349115293    6206  6206          20
2   100284 2015-03-13 00:05:20            2015-03-13 00:15:00                 9.345457793    6206  2420         580
3   100284 2015-03-13 00:15:00            2015-03-13 00:20:00      I15        4.609846782    2420  2420         300
4   100284 2015-03-13 00:20:00        I15 2015-03-13 00:34:34      I15        6.097244827    2420  2420         874
5   100284 2015-03-13 00:34:34        I15 2015-03-13 00:36:52      I15        0.112831213    2420  2420         138
6   100284 2015-03-13 00:36:52        I15 2015-03-13 00:37:52      I15        0.051011669    2420  2420          60
7   100284 2015-03-13 00:37:52        I15 2015-03-13 00:50:00      I15        8.244393968    2420  2420         728
8   100284 2015-03-13 00:50:00        I15 2015-03-13 00:57:06                 7.900808243    2420  6188         426
9   100284 2015-03-13 00:57:06            2015-03-13 00:58:14                 1.298096162    6188  6019          68
10  100284 2015-03-13 00:58:14            2015-03-13 01:03:30                 1.782517401    6019  6188         316
11  100284 2015-03-13 01:03:30            2015-03-13 01:05:18                 0.002000153    6188  6188         108
12  100284 2015-03-13 01:05:18            2015-03-13 01:25:34                 0.052831508    6188  6188        1216
13  100284 2015-03-13 01:25:34            2015-03-13 01:35:00                 6.471993106    6188  6183         566
14  100284 2015-03-13 01:35:00            2015-03-13 01:35:20                 0.398436396    6183  6183          20
15  100665 2015-03-01 20:46:00            2015-03-01 20:51:00                 4.916207734    6180  6188         300
16  100665 2015-03-01 20:51:00            2015-03-01 20:56:00                 4.977879172    6188  6019         300
17  100665 2015-03-01 20:56:00            2015-03-01 20:57:22      I15        1.339368219    6019  2420          82
18  100665 2015-03-01 20:57:22        I15 2015-03-01 21:01:00      I15        3.489645997    2420  2420         218
19  100665 2015-03-01 21:01:00        I15 2015-03-01 21:06:00      I15        5.181996399    2420  2420         300
20  100665 2015-03-01 21:06:16        I15 2015-03-01 21:11:00      I15        4.193124975    2420  2420         284
21  100665 2015-03-01 21:11:00        I15 2015-03-01 21:16:00      I15        3.247763697    2420  2420         300
22  100665 2015-03-01 21:16:00        I15 2015-03-01 21:21:00      I15        4.074412199    2420  2420         300
23  100665 2015-03-01 21:21:00        I15 2015-03-01 21:26:00      I15        4.282198968    2420  2420         300
24  100665 2015-03-01 21:26:00        I15 2015-03-01 21:28:48                 2.661758135    2420  6205         168
25  100665 2015-03-01 21:28:48            2015-03-01 21:31:00                 2.281483570    6205  6030         132
         mins speedbtwpnts stopmove  starttime           pretrip timestopped
1   0.3333333  62.84075269        1 1426205100 100284_1426205100   0.3333333
2   9.6666667  58.00628975        1 1426205100 100284_1426205100   0.0000000
3   5.0000000  55.31816138        1 1426205100 100284_1426205100   0.0000000
4  14.5666667  25.11450958        1 1426205100 100284_1426205100   0.0000000
5   2.3000000   2.94342294        0 1426205100 100284_1426205100   2.3000000
6   1.0000000   3.06070012        0 1426205100 100284_1426205100   3.3000000
7  12.1333333  40.76898116        1 1426205100 100284_1426205100   0.0000000
8   7.1000000  66.76739360        1 1426205100 100284_1426205100   0.0000000
9   1.1333333  68.72273800        1 1426205100 100284_1426205100   0.0000000
10  5.2666667  20.30716027        1 1426205100 100284_1426205100   0.0000000
11  1.8000000   0.06667178        0 1426205100 100284_1426205100   1.8000000
12 20.2666667   0.15640907        0 1426205100 100284_1426205100  22.0666700
13  9.4333333  41.16462046        1 1426205100 100284_1426205100   0.0000000
14  0.3333333  71.71855135        1 1426205100 100284_1426205100   0.0000000
15  5.0000000  58.99449281        1 1425242760 100665_1425242760   0.0000000
16  5.0000000  59.73455007        1 1425242760 100665_1425242760   0.0000000
17  1.3666667  58.80153156        1 1425242760 100665_1425242760   0.0000000
18  3.6333333  57.62718160        1 1425242760 100665_1425242760   0.0000000
19  5.0000000  62.18395678        1 1425242760 100665_1425242760   0.0000000
20  4.7333333  53.15228842        1 1425242760 100665_1425242760   0.0000000
21  5.0000000  38.97316437        1 1425242760 100665_1425242760   0.0000000
22  5.0000000  48.89294639        1 1425242760 100665_1425242760   0.0000000
23  5.0000000  51.38638762        1 1425242760 100665_1425242760   0.0000000
24  2.8000000  57.03767432        1 1425242760 100665_1425242760   0.0000000
25  2.2000000  62.22227919        1 1425242760 100665_1425242760   0.0000000
```

However, this does not scale very well, and I cannot figure out how to vectorize multiple conditions all at once. The closest I have gotten is the following; its only for the first condition and it is not what I want as it returns `FALSE` for every instance of `build$cond`:

```
cond1 <- c(FALSE, (build[-nrow(build), 14] == build[-1, 14]))
    build$cond1 <- cond1
cond2 <- c(FALSE, (build[-1, 12] == 1))
    build$cond2 <- cond2
cond3 <- c((build[ , 12] == 0))
    build$cond3 <- cond3
cond <- cond1 & cond2 & cond3
    build$cond <- cond
```

Any help could be greatly appreciated.

**Edit** Added `dput()` below:

```
dput(build[1:25,])
structure(list(truckid = c(100284L, 100284L, 100284L, 100284L, 
100284L, 100284L, 100284L, 100284L, 100284L, 100284L, 100284L, 
100284L, 100284L, 100284L, 100665L, 100665L, 100665L, 100665L, 
100665L, 100665L, 100665L, 100665L, 100665L, 100665L, 100665L
), readdate_from = structure(c(1426205100, 1426205120, 1426205700, 
1426206000, 1426206874, 1426207012, 1426207072, 1426207800, 1426208226, 
1426208294, 1426208610, 1426208718, 1426209934, 1426210500, 1425242760, 
1425243060, 1425243360, 1425243442, 1425243660, 1425243976, 1425244260, 
1425244560, 1425244860, 1425245160, 1425245328), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), route_from = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("", "I10", "I15", "I17", 
"I19", "I40", "I8"), class = "factor"), to_readdate = structure(c(1426205120, 
1426205700, 1426206000, 1426206874, 1426207012, 1426207072, 1426207800, 
1426208226, 1426208294, 1426208610, 1426208718, 1426209934, 1426210500, 
1426210520, 1425243060, 1425243360, 1425243442, 1425243660, 1425243960, 
1425244260, 1425244560, 1425244860, 1425245160, 1425245328, 1425245460
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), to_route = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "I10", "I15", 
"I17", "I19", "I40", "I8"), class = "factor"), distance_travelled = c(0.3491152927, 
9.3454577932, 4.6098467817, 6.0972448268, 0.1128312127, 0.0510116686, 
8.2443939681, 7.9008082426, 1.2980961622, 1.7825174014, 0.0020001533, 
0.052831508, 6.4719931061, 0.3984363964, 4.9162077343, 4.9778791724, 
1.3393682188, 3.4896459968, 5.1819963986, 4.1931249754, 3.2477636975, 
4.0744121993, 4.2821989681, 2.6617581347, 2.2814835704), TTTfrom = c(6206, 
6206, 2420, 2420, 2420, 2420, 2420, 2420, 6188, 6019, 6188, 6188, 
6188, 6183, 6180, 6188, 6019, 2420, 2420, 2420, 2420, 2420, 2420, 
2420, 6205), toTTT = c(6206, 2420, 2420, 2420, 2420, 2420, 2420, 
6188, 6019, 6188, 6188, 6188, 6183, 6183, 6188, 6019, 2420, 2420, 
2420, 2420, 2420, 2420, 2420, 6205, 6030), timebtwpnts = c(20, 
580, 300, 874, 138, 60, 728, 426, 68, 316, 108, 1216, 566, 20, 
300, 300, 82, 218, 300, 284, 300, 300, 300, 168, 132), mins = c(0.333333333333333, 
9.66666666666667, 5, 14.5666666666667, 2.3, 1, 12.1333333333333, 
7.1, 1.13333333333333, 5.26666666666667, 1.8, 20.2666666666667, 
9.43333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 5, 5, 1.36666666666667, 
3.63333333333333, 5, 4.73333333333333, 5, 5, 5, 2.8, 2.2), speedbtwpnts = c(62.840752686, 
58.0062897508966, 55.3181613804, 25.1145095840732, 2.94342294, 
3.060700116, 40.7689811609341, 66.7673935994366, 68.7227379988235, 
20.3071602691139, 0.0666717766666667, 0.156409069736842, 41.1646204628269, 
71.718551352, 58.9944928116, 59.7345500688, 58.8015315570732, 
57.6271815985321, 62.1839567832, 53.1522884205634, 38.97316437, 
48.8929463916, 51.3863876172, 57.037674315, 62.2222791927273), 
    stopmove = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("truckid", "readdate_from", 
"route_from", "to_readdate", "to_route", "distance_travelled", 
"TTTfrom", "toTTT", "timebtwpnts", "mins", "speedbtwpnts", "stopmove"
), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Note that you are misusing `ifelse` which is a vectorized function, in contrast to the `if` statement which is more appropriate for your use-case.

Comment: Could you please post `dput(build[1:25, ])`? This will help us easily access your data.

Comment: @ josilber just added, dput(build[1:25, ]) output above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first sanity fix:

```
res <- c(build$mins[1], 2:length(build$pretrip))
same_trip <- c(FALSE, (build$pretrip[-1] == build$pretrip[-nrow(build)]) )
cond1 <- c(FALSE, (build$stopmove[-nrow(build)] == 1) & (build$stopmove[-1] == 0) ) )
cond2 <- ...

for (i in 1:length(build$pretrip)) {

     if( same_trip[i] ) {
        if( cond1[i] ) {
           res[i] <- build$mins[i]
        } else if (cond2[i]) {
           res[i] <- round(res[i-1] + build$mins[i], 5)
        } else {
           res[i] <- 0
        }
     } else {
        if( build$stopmove[i] == 0 ) {
           res[i] <- build$mins[i]
        } else {
           res[i] <- 0
        }
     }
}
build$timestopped <- res
```

and now we can actually see the difficulty/problem, in res[i] <- round(res[i-1] + build$mins[i], 5) you need the value before, in all other cases you can use the ifelse function on a vector, therefore my suggestion would be:

```
same_trip <- c(FALSE, (build$pretrip[-1] == build$pretrip[-nrow(build)]) )
cond1 <- c(FALSE, (build$stopmove[-nrow(build)] == 1) & (build$stopmove[-1] == 0) ) )
cond2 <- ...

res <- ifelse( (same_trip & cond1) | (build$stopmove[i] == 0),
                build$mins,
                0)

for (i in 1:length(build$pretrip)) {
   if( same_trip[i] && cond2[i]) {
      res[i] <- round(res[i-1] + build$mins[i], 5)
   }
}
build$timestopped <- res
```

if you know that cond2 can't be true twice in a row, you can also convert that to a vector operation, otherwise you are generally stuck with it. (There could be a cumsum hack, but I don't think so)

EDIT

I think the best solution is additionally reducing the for loop to only go over the cases you need:

```
for (i in (1:length(build$pretrip))[same_trip & cond2]  ) {
    res[i] <- round(res[i-1] + build$mins[i], 5)
}
```

I don't think a quicker (and still easily understandable) solution is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need a loop there at all.

The vector `cond` will be `TRUE` when the i^th row and the (i - 1)^th row have the same truck ID and will be `FALSE` otherwise. You don't have to iterate over cond then, just use

```
res <- ifelse(cond, c(0, res[1:(nrow(res)-1)]), res)
```

ifelse() works on vectors.

The 0 is used as the first element in that vector because `res[0]` is undefined (so `cond[1]` is `FALSE` or `undefined`) but if we used `NA` the product would also be `NA`.

This should return the prior value of `res` for any row where the equivalent row of `cond` is `TRUE` and the same row of `res` for all rows where `cond` is `FALSE`.

Comment: Missing a closing parenthesis for that `c(` ? Also, if `res` has rows, you'll need a comma before the `]`, right?

Comment: Yes, there was a missing `)` and the comma would be needed if `res` has more than one dimension. The `ifelse` solution is cleaner, I overlooked/overthought it when dealing with the lagging of `res`. murgs edit cleans it up.

Comment: If `res` has only one dimension, `nrow(res)` is `NULL`, I guess, unless it's a one-column matrix. Your syntax would be fine for a data.table, since they don't demand the extra comma. Maybe you want `length` instead of `nrow`? Anyway, small difference. I just read your answer and not the very long question.